# Send JSON with list to Controller

Tags: asp.net-core

I am trying to send following JSON to my controller:

```
 [
    {
    "collection": "col1",
    "uuid": [
          "11:22:33:44:55:66",
         "11:22:33:44:55:66"
        ]
    },
    {
        "collection": "test"
    }
 ]
```

Every object "collection" contains a list of strings symbolized by the uuids.

My model looks like this:

```
public class DummyDeviceApiModel {

[Display(Name = "UUID")]
[StringLength(36)]
public List<string> uuid {get; set;}

[Display(Name = "Collection")]
public string collection {get; set;}


}
```

and my controller function like this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<DummyDeviceModel>> PostCreateDummyDevice(List<DummyDeviceApiModel> ddpm)
```

What works is when I just send the collection part, but the UUID with its list makes problem:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]' to type
> 'System.String'

.

Any idea what I am doing wrong? The issue seems to be the "second" list in the model.

Thanks
Stephan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[StringLength(36)]` is a validation attribute for type `string` not `arrays` of `string` or `List<string>`. The exception is probably happening behind the scenes as it tries to `validate` on your property since it is of type `List<string>`. If you want to do what I think you do, create a custom validation on your list to make sure you only have strings in your list which are less than or equal to a length of 36, then you need to either implement `IValidatableObject` on your model (class) or create a custom `Validation Attribute` for validation by creating a class which inherits from `ValidationAttribute`. You can read more about how to implement this interface and/or create a custom attribute at MSDN: (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1). As a test to see if it is indeed the `StringLength` attribute which is throwing the exception, comment out that particular `Validation Attribute` in your code and see if it runs without error.